# Why notify tasks aren't getting executed in ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

The problem I am facing is quite common, but the other solutions didn't work for me. As the question suggests, when I run my playbook, only the first notify handler gets executed. i.e. only firewalld is restarted, but updated bash profile isn't sourced.

Some people suggested notify chaining, but I wouldn't like to merge two tasks with completely different objectives. For example, one task could be adding ports to firewalld and then restarting it; another could be update my bash profile to display date with `history` command output.

N.B. the above snippet isn't my full .yml, only a part of it, so this may or may not work. But, the original file does work.

```
---
  tasks  
   - name: add port-80 to firewalld
     firewalld: zone=drop port=80/tcp permanent=true state=enabled

   - name: add port-443 to firewalld
     firewalld: zone=drop port=443/tcp permanent=true state=enabled

   - shell: firewall-cmd --reload
     notify:
      - Restart firewalld

   - name: Enabling time display in history
     blockinfile:
     dest: ~/.bash_profile
     block: |
         export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
     notify:
      - Source the updated Bash profile


  handlers:
   - name: Restart firewalld
     service: name=firewalld state=restarted

   - name: Source the updated Bash profile
     shell: source ~/.bash_profile

...
```

Comment: Given the triggering tasks do really report a changed state, this should work exactly like that. Both handlers should get fired. Are your sure the handler is not executed or does it simply not have the expected outcome?

Comment: BTW, your `blockinfile`` task is not formatted correctly. But I guess this only is a formatting issue in your post, not your real playbook because that would give you errors during execution.

Comment: @udondan, I'm sure that handler is not executed, because a `debug` under notify didn't work.

Comment: As @udondan points out, if the task doesn't result in a change then the handler(s) won't be called.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, Your comments let me think again and I have got my solution. You are welcome to contribute by improving my answer or even giving a seperate answer. I will consider accepting them

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally, I have figured out the problem with the help of comments.

> The notify handler will be executed if and only if state is `changed` as a result of the task.

The mistake I am doing is trying to install a package that is already installed. So, state wasn't getting changed.

Let's see it with an example,

```
---
- hosts: varnish
  remote_user: root

  tasks:    
   - name: Install tree
     yum: name=tree state=absent
     notify:
      - Do an echo

  handlers:
   - name: Do an echo
     debug: msg="This will be printed"    
...
```

We will run the play book two times.

After first run, we will get:

```
TASK [Install tree] ************************************************************
changed: [192.***.***.**]

RUNNING HANDLER [Do an echo] ***************************************************
ok: [192.***.***.**] => {
    "msg": "This will be printed"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.***.***.**             : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

As the state is changed ( Look at the `changed=1` part ), debug message will be printed.

After second run, we will get:

```
TASK [Install tree] ************************************************************
ok: [192.***.***.**]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.***.***.**             : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

The thing to look at is handler isn't called unlike first run, because state isn't changed in the second run ( tree is already installed ).

I have posted it as an answer, it may help the fellow users.

Comment: Good answer.  When debugging this, it can be useful to add `changed_when: true` to the task making the notification, to force the changed state.